# To keep periods in acronyms or not in a database?

Tags: mysql, regex

Acronyms are a pain in my database, especially when doing a search. I haven't decided if I should accept periods during search queries. These are the problems I face when searching:

- 'IRQ' will not find 'I.R.Q.'
- 'I.R.Q' will not find 'IRQ'
- 'IRQ.' or 'IR.Q' will not find 'IRQ' or 'I.R.Q.'

etc...

The same problem goes for ellipses (...) or three series of periods.

I just need to know what directions should I take with this issue:

- Is it better to remove all periods when inserting the string to the database?
- If so what regex can I use to identify periods (instead of ellipses or three series of periods) to identify what needs to be removed?
- If it is possible to keep the periods in acronyms, how can it be scripted in a query to find 'I.R.Q' if I input 'IRQ' in the search field, through MySQL using regex or maybe a MySQL function I don't know about?

Comment: I think this is a good question and don't know why people are voting to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My responses for each question:

- **Is it better to remove all periods when inserting the string to the database?**

Yes and no. You want the database to have the original text. If you want, create a separate field that is "cleaned up" to search against. Here, you can remove periods, make everything lowercase, etc.

- **If so what regex can I use to identify periods (instead of ellipses or three series of periods) to identify what needs to be removed?**

  /\.+/

That finds one or more periods in a given spot. But you'll want to integrate it with your search formula.

Note: regex on a database isn't known to have high performance. Be cautious with this.

Other note: you may want to use FullText search in MySQL. This also, isn't known to have high performance with data sets over 1000+ entries. If you have big data and need fulltext search, use Sphinx (available as a MySQL plug-in and RAM-based indexing system).

- **If it is possible to keep the periods in acronyms, how can it be scripted in a query to find 'I.R.Q' if I input 'IRQ' in the search field, through MySQL using regex or maybe a MySQL function I don't know about?**

Yes, by having the 2 fields I described in the first bullet's answer.

Comment: I'd extend “regex on a database isn't known to have high performance” to the stronger “regex on a database is known to have low performance”, which is due to the fact that they force a linear table scan (or worse, with complex queries). There are some theoretically-optimizable cases, but they're the ones which you can handle without regexes. But having a separate “cleaned up text” column is an *excellent* suggestion.

Comment: Thinking about now, for over 3000+ records regex will definitely affect performance. Creating another column as 'cleaned' string is the best way to go. The clean column will input all lowercase letters and remove accents and symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the sanctity of your input.  If it is not yours to alter then don't alter it.  Instead you should have a separate system to allow for text searching, and *that* can alter the text as it sees fit to be able to handle these types of issues.

Have a read up on Lucene, and specifically Lucene's standard analyzer, to see the types of changes that are commonly carried out to allow successful searching of complex text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `REGEXP` function of MySQL to send an acronym :

```
SELECT col1, col2...coln FROM yourTable WHERE colWithAcronym REGEXP "#I\.?R\.?Q\.?#"
```

If you use PHP you can build your regexp by this simple loop :

```
$result = "#";
foreach($yourAcronym as $char){
    $result.=$char."\\.?";
}
$result.="#";
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are searching for is a fulltext search. Mysql supports this for myisam-tables, but not for innodb. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Alternatively you could go for an external framework that provides that funcionality. Lucene is a popular open-source one. ([lucene.apache.org](http://lucene.apache.org))

Answer (score 0):

There would be 2 methods,

```
1. save data -removing symbols from text and match accordingly,
2. you can make a regex ,like this for eg.

select * from table where acronym regexp '^[A-Z]+[.]?[A-Z]+[.]?[A-Z]+[.]?$';
```

Please note, however, that this requires the acronym to be stored in uppercase. If you don't want the case to matter, just change [A-Z] to [A-Za-z].